# match function is giving an error in Supabase flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-database

I'm trying to fetch some data from the database using the code

```
  Supabase.instance.client
      .from('delivery')
      .select('location')
      .match({'order': 'test'})
      .then((value){print(value);});
```

unfortunately it gives mt the error

```
PostgrestException(message: "failed to parse order (eq.test)" (line 1, column 4), code: PGRST100, details: unexpected "t" expecting "asc", "desc", "nullsfirst" or "nullslast", hint: null)
E/flutter (10564): #0      PostgrestBuilder._parseResponse (package:postgrest/src/postgrest_builder.dart:323:7)
E/flutter (10564): #1      PostgrestBuilder._execute (package:postgrest/src/postgrest_builder.dart:198:14)
E/flutter (10564): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10564): #2      PostgrestBuilder.then (package:postgrest/src/postgrest_builder.dart:400:24)
E/flutter (10564): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10564):
```

any ideas how can i solve that ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Is this a simplified version of your code? If it is, could you share your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was fixed by renaming the 'order' column to something else, like custom_order.

It's likely reserved for a built-in postgrest feature.